# Como habilitar PHP Sessions no Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou desenvolvendo meu site usando a plataforma Wordpress.

Eu precisava muito, mas muito mesmo, habilitar o PHP Sessions dentro da plataforma,
para que os usuários logados mantenham-se logados dentro dos subdomínios que eu estou criando.

Alguma sugestão? Eu já tentei habilitar isso por um plugin, mas não funcionou. Deu mensagens de erro no cabeçalho.

**Observação**: A versão do wordpress que estou usando é 4.3

Comment: Cara, eu fiz uma coisa dessas a um tempinho. Assim que eu lembrar como fiz eu te mando aqui

Comment: Tente também: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sua melhor saída não seria a implementação de um SSO (Single-Sign-On)? Existem vários disponíveis no repositório: https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/single-sign-on. Particularmente, testei o Auth0 com c# e foi muito simples.

Answer (score 2):

Olá tenta fazer uma das opções:

No PHP de forma genérica usa assim:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.domain.tld');
if ( empty(session_id()) ) session_start();
```

No .htaccess:

```
php_value session.cookie_domain .example.com
```

No WordPress wp-config.php:

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.domain.tld');
```

Esta sessão só pode ser compartilhada em uma única instalação do WordPress. Quer dizer, se você tiver outros subdomínios com outra instalação do WordPress, essa configuração pode não funcionar, uma vez que o WordPress tem outra sessão para outra instalação.

Talvez ajude :)

Comment: Ótimo raciocínio. Parabéns!